# Mais de um retorno em um método no PHP

Tags: php, método

Por exemplo tenho a seguinte função:

```
<?php

public function login($username, $password) {
  if($condicao === 1) {
     return true, 
  } elseif($condicao === 2) {
    return 'qualquer string';
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Como faço pra usar desta forma uma função com 3 ou mais retornos, com dois usuáriamos assim:

```
if($login->login($username, $password)) {
  echo 'foi';
} else {
  echo 'não foi';
}
```

Deu pra entender?

### EDITADO

```
if (count($cookie) === 12) {
    Session::set('ct0', $ct0[0]);
    return true;
} elseif (count($cookie) === 13) {
    return 'bloqued';
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Vamos supor que o exemplo acima é uma função feita com `curl` onde se existir login e senha corretos me retorna `true`, se a conta estiver bloqueada, me retorna 'bloqued', se os dados inseridos estiver errados me retorna `false`;

Ficando assim:

```
public function login($username, $password) {
    curl...

    if (count($cookie) === 12) {
        return true;
    } elseif (count($cookie) === 13) {
        return 'bloqued';
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


// Modo de usar

if ($login->login($username, $password)) {
    echo json_encode([
            'error'     => false,
            'message'   => 'Logado com sucesso, aguarde...'
        ]
    );
} elseif($login->login($username, $password) !== true && $login->login($username, $password) !== false) {
    echo json_encode([
            'error' => true,
            'message' => 'Conta bloqueada',
        ]
    );
} else {
    echo json_encode([
            'error'     => true,
            'message'   => 'Usuário e/ou Senha incorretos'
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: A variável `$condicao` existe ?

Comment: é só um exemplo tentei explicar, quero saber como uso uma função que retorna mais de tres valores. Entende?

Comment: Deu não. Faz sentido ter três retornos diferentes na função, principalmente se tratando de tipo diferentes? E o que exatamente quer verificar com o `if`?

Comment: Há um erro na linha do primeiro `return`, pois você está usando `,` sendo que tem que ser `;`

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza, sim foi erro de digitação fiz o código aqui mesmo, Anderson Carlos Woss, vou editar o tópico.

Comment: @LoucãoDEV, podes ver que funciona com mais retornos [ideone](https://ideone.com/EovANa).. Seria bom colocar mais informação sobre o código.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, @WéllingthonM.deSouza eu tentei com um exemplo parecido que vc colocou nos comentarios e não consegui.

Comment: `$cookie` é um *Array* ?

Comment: Exato. Sim é um array, apenas o $cookie[4] removi umas strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem várias formas, na verdade o que você quer não é "Mais de um retorno", inclusive.

Mas, você poderia fazer:

```
const ERR_MENOR_QUE_UM = 0;
const ERR_MAIOR_QUE_VINTE = -1;
const ERR_DIVISIVEL_POR_DOIS = -2;

function verificarNumero($n)
{
    if($n < 0){
        return ERR_MENOR_QUE_UM;
    }

    if($n > 20){
        return ERR_MAIOR_QUE_VINTE;
    }

    if($n % 2 === 0){
        return ERR_DIVISIVEL_POR_DOIS;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Dessa forma bastaria fazer:

```
if(verificarNumero(2) === true){
    echo 'Nenhum erro ocorreu';
}
```

Se não, como é o caso, você teria três resultados possíveis:

```
if(verificarNumero(2) === ERR_DIVISIVEL_POR_DOIS){
    echo 'Número inválido, divisível por dois';
}
```

Você também pode utilizar `switch` para tal finalidade.

---

Agora se você quer retornar mais de um valor realmente você pode usar uma array:

```
function fatorial($n)
{
    $f = array_product(range($n, 1));

    if ($f >= PHP_INT_MAX) {
        return [$f, true];
    }

    return [$f, false];
}
```

Agora de fato você retorna dois valores, isso não é muito comum no PHP, embora isso possa ser extremamente comum em outras linguagens. Você também poderia fazer somente `return [array_product(range($n, 1)), $f >= PHP_INT_MAX];`, mas acredito que isto ficaria mais confuso.

Para utilizar isso você poderia fazer:

```
list($resultado, $erro) = fatorial(10);

if($erro === false){
  echo $resultado;
}else{
  echo 'Algo deu errado';
}
```

Comment: Deu certo porém não consigo verificar a quantidades de cookies, por exemplo: uma conta com dados corretos recebe tantos cookies, uma conta com dados errados recebe tantos cookies, e uma conta bloqueada no twitter recebe outra quantidade de cookies. :(

Answer (score 1):

Altere a condição de:

```
// Modo de usar

if ($login->login($username, $password))
```

Para:

```
// Modo de usar

if ($login->login($username, $password) === true)
```

Veja esse artigo: [Quando usar == ou === em php?](http://blog.alura.com.br/quando-usar-ou-em-php/) no Blog da Alura.

Comment: Opa quase consegui. problema agora é na contagem dos cookies

Comment: @LoucãoDEV, que bom, considere marcar como util, agora para esse outro problema, recomendo abrir outra pergunta.